# Why is Next-hop address the same with Interface address in forwarding table?

Tags: routing, ip, ip-forwarding-table

I read about [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1: The Protocols (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321336313) 5.4.3.1 Direct Delivery, this chapter illustrate the direct delivery like below:[image]
But what confuse me is the forwarding table of **S**:
[image]
As you can see, in the second entry of the forwarding table of **S**, the Next hop address and Interface address are the same, I don't think this will make any sense because I think 10.0.0.100 is the IP address of **S**, so the Interface address of these two entries should be 10.0.0.100, but the Next hop address of the second entry should be the IP address of **D**, not 10.0.0.100, just like the first entry, 10.0.0.1 is the IP address of R, am I right? if not, please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the gateway address for a route points to one of the host's interfaces it means "I'm the gateway, I'm able to transmit to this destination directly."